# How to fix error 127 when running NPM from php environment using exec()?

Tags: php, npm, command

I'm trying to bundle scripts via NPM in a PHP environment using the exec() function. Whatever setup I try, I keep ending up with a 127 error code from the terminal.

I first checked whether Node was properly working. The following code returns a proper version number (v11.9.0):

```
/**
* Check if Node is working..
*/
$script = exec('cd ../ && node -v', $output, $status);

return [$script, $output, $status];
```

The problem arises when I want to use NPM. For example, the following command returns a 127 status code (command not found):

```
/**
* Try to run npm from command line
*/
$script = exec('cd ../ && npm run production', $output, $status);

return [$script, $output, $status];
```

Trying the version number to see if NPM is installed at all..

```
/**
* Trying to find NPM version number..
*/
$script = exec('cd ../ && npm --version', $output, $status);

return [$script, $output, $status];
```

Also returns a 127 status code (command not found), which leads me to believe NPM is not functioning at all.

I have been pulling my hairs out over this one for several hours now. I'd like to be able to compile my scripts via this PHP environment.

If anyone has any ideas, please let me know.

Comment: Does `npm` work from the command line itself?

Comment: Yes, `npm` works from the command line itself.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late but for someone else having the same issue.

Here, what I did.

```
exec('PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.0.3/bin:$PATH && PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH && npm run prod', $output, $status);
```

You need to set paths first then run `npm`